# Excel - List return distinct data from other column with duplicate values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to return distinct values for each unique Primary Key.

#### Some data...

[image]

#### Desired Output

[image]

- For UNIQUE IDS I am using the unique function on excel 365.
- For CLASS column I do not know how to return distinct values.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your output from your input, you can use (in O365)

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Class],Table1[ID]=D2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Your formula sets the values for **Class** column. It might be worth adding the formula to get unique **ID's** as well... unless I've miss read your formula

Comment: @Zac  I was answering the question as written, which included that the OP was using the UNIQUE function to get the unique ID's.  I thought it unnecessary to repeat that.  I did add the caveat about O365 for other readers, though.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I missed that comment... my bad

Comment: @RonRosenfeld.... This syntax can work with Ranges... Without using ```table[class]```  ... something like this:  ```=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(DM:DM,M:M=M4))))```  With this syntax it is not working.   Thanks for sharing !!!!

Comment: @AndreNevares Yes, you can always replace structured references with their regular equivalents. I prefer using tables since the references are dynamic, and I don't have to guess (or use whole column ranges which can slow things down) at the maximum size.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sorry for delay,  It worked just FINE!   Thanks a lot.   I have to translate this into EXCEL pt-BR (brazilian version) ...  The final formula for Brazilian Users:  __ =UNIRTEXTO(", ";VERDADEIRO;CLASSIFICAR(ÚNICO(FILTRO(Q7:Q10000;K7:K10000=K7)))) __ .  Thanks for Sharing.  I Will check your answer.   GOOD JOB!